# Getting an error message stored procedure not found

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert into a table using a stored procedure. But when I try to insert my data using a button click, an error message appears saying

> Stored procedure not found

My code:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure", sqlcon);
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Is `Procedure` the name of a stored procedure in the database/Initial Catalog of your connection string?

Comment: yes Procedure is the name

Comment: Did you create the procedure in the **correct** database - the one you're connecting to in your application? Can you see the procedure in SSMS Object Explorer in the database you want it to be in??

Comment: The default database may not be set.  That is what Jonathon is referring.  Either in connection string put initial database, or SqlCommand("Use DatabaseName; Procedure", sqlcon);

Comment: Check the connection string  and change the name of your procedure then try again...

Comment: `Procedure` is a keyword. If you insist in using this name you should bracket it `[Procedure]`

Comment: Change the stored procedure name to something that is MEANINGFUL, and not a SQL Keyword, and you might have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create any `stored procedure` with name `procedure`.

Sql itself give error while creating this.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 248
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.

Please check your database again, since this procedure is not created in `DB`, so error is obvious.